# Flask does not direct to the home page

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications, endpoint

I'm am using flask and trying to access my homepage after the login and when trying to click on the log in button, the endpoint for the home is not getting called.

Below is my **app.py** file.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect, url_for
from tensorflow import keras

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    print('success1')
    return render_template(r'index.html')

@app.route('/success')
def success():
    # return 'logged in successfully'
    print('success')
    render_template(r'Home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Below is my **index.html** code. (login form) Only the  tag is added below.

```
<form id = "login-form" action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="d-grid">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="login-form-submit">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Below is the **validation.js** file I have created.

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");

loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    if (username === "user" && password === "user123") {
        alert("You have successfully logged in.");
        window.location.replace("{{ url_for('success') }}");
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

When I click on the sigh in button, I do get the alert saying 'you have successfully logged in' but I'm not getting redirected to the home.html. I suspect that something is wrong in the way that I call the endpoint in my javascript file.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Hello, did you forget to add the request types to your route? ex. methods=['GET', 'POST']

Comment: @MahmudAlptekin Thanks for the response. I tried adding methods to the app.py endpoint and now I'm taken into a 404 page.

Comment: Check your HTML files name you are trying to render

Comment: @MahmudAlptekin I have checked that as well and the home.html resides in the templates folder, in which the flask will check for template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with the Javascript validation but the below python and html code works for me:

```
@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template(r'home.html')
```

---

```
<form id = "login-form" action="{{ url_for('success') }}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="d-grid">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="login-form-submit">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I could use the above answer and successfully get redirected to the home.html. Further, I could append the username and password check with was done through the java script to the if condition inside the decorator to achieve that.